# Copy files in a folder structure to their respective sub-folder with Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, move

I want to move the file "file_to_move.txt"in each folder to their respective "done"-folder.

so the **file_to_move.txt** in **C:\Temp\test\folder1** is moved to **C:\Temp\test\folder1\done**
and **file_to_move.txt** in **C:\Temp\test\folder2** is moved to **C:\Temp\test\folder2\done**

...and so on, preferably with a %date%_%time% added to the file-name.

if a folder (like folder4 in the example below) does not have a file_to_move.txt, the script should just ignore it and move on.

folder structure example:

- C:\Temp\test\DONE
- C:\Temp\test\folder1
- C:\Temp\test\folder1\done
- C:\Temp\test\folder1\some_other_folder
- C:\Temp\test\folder1\some_other_file.txt
- C:\Temp\test\folder1\file_to_move.txt
- C:\Temp\test\folder2
- C:\Temp\test\folder2\done
- C:\Temp\test\folder2\some_other_folder
- C:\Temp\test\folder2\some_other_file.txt
- C:\Temp\test\folder2\file_to_move.txt
- C:\Temp\test\folder3
- C:\Temp\test\folder3\done
- C:\Temp\test\folder3\some_other_folder
- C:\Temp\test\folder3\some_other_file.txt
- C:\Temp\test\folder3\file_to_move.txt
- C:\Temp\test\folder4
- C:\Temp\test\folder4\done
- C:\Temp\test\folder4\some_other_folder
- C:\Temp\test\folder4\some_other_file.txt

I have experimented with a Powershell script even if I'm not very good at it and I dont know it can be done in a standard batch-script.
I have tried this so far:

In a batch-script:

```
SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%bin\movescript.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PowerShellScriptPath%'"
```

in the movescript.ps1:

```
Move-Item C:\Temp\test\*\file_to_move.txt C:\Temp\test\*\done\file_to_move_$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd_HHmmss).txt
```

But this is not working.
I guess it's not precise enough to work.

As a bonus, can the whole thing be done within the basic script or must we use the external .PS1-file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet with a filter to retrieve all `file_to_move.txt` files recursively from a path. Use the [Foreach-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113300) (alias foreach) to iterate over them and combine the new path using the [Join-Path](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113347) cmdlet. To Copy the Item, you can use the [Copy-Item](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113292) cmdlet:

```
$itemsToCopy = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\Temp\Test -Filter file_to_move.txt -Recurse 
$itemsToCopy | foreach {
    $newPath = Join-Path $_.DirectoryName 'done'
    New-Item -Path $newPath -ItemType directory -Force | out-null
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $newPath
}
```

If you want to add a Timestamp, you could use the [Get-Date](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113313) cmdlet and invoke the `ToString` method with your desired format on it, example:

```
(Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-dd-M_HH-mm-ss")
```

Output:

```
2016-05-4_15-06-02
```

You can now concat the filenames using a format string and the `$_.Basename` and `$_.Extension` property within your foreach loop. I will leave this as an exercise to you.